# C++: Issue with creating int array with conditions in loop

Tags: c++, arrays, conditional-statements

I have the following code:

```
size_t function(T* arr, size_t size, FUN f){
    size_t a = 0;
    size_t b = 0;
    int a2[size];
    for (int y = 0; y<size; y++){
        if (f(arr[y])){
            a2[0+a] = arr[y];
            ++count_good;
        } else if (f(arr[y]) == false){
            a2[size-b] = arr[y];
            ++count_bad;
        }
    }
    copy(a2, a2 + sizeof(a2) / sizeof(a2[0]), arr);
    return a;
}
```

Which should arrange the a2 according to the condition: if true, put the values in the front to the array; if result of function is false, put them to the back.

However, if I set

`int arr[6]={10,3,9,6,3,2}`;

the result of my function is

`int arr[6]={10,6,2,0,3,9}`;

As you can see, one of the values has been changed to 0.

Any ideas where does this come from?

Thanks

Comment: Post your actual code.

Comment: WIthout understanding what `f` is actually passed as, what the value of `size` represents, etc, it's pretty difficult to even GUESS what the problem is - but it looks like you you have out-of range access for your `a2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues.

1. Simply use [`std::partion`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) or [`std::partion_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy)  instead. You can then use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to calculate the number of "good" elements, via using the return value of the `partition`. No need to reinvent the wheel.
2. Simply use an `else` branch instead of an `else if`, you are needlessly doing the check twice.
3. You neither increment `a` nor `b`. You should rename `a` to `count_good` and `b` to `count_bad`.
4. You need to call `a2[size-count_bad - 1]`, otherwise you have an off by one error by accessing `a2[size]`.
5. C++ does not allow dynamic arrays. Since `size` is not known on compilation `int a2[size];` is non-conformat. Use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your `size` denotes number of elements in an array, the line

```
a2[size-b] = arr[y];
```

exceeds the size when `b = 0`.
So, you are assigning values one element too far.